# How to idiomatically access object attribute missing from type definition

Tags: typescript

I have a case where I know for certain an attribute will be present on an object returned by an external library. For some reason the attribute is missing from the type definition provided by that library.

Sample code:

```
const thing = getThing()
const f = thing.features[0]; // Property 'features' does not exist on type 'Thing'
```

What is the appropriate way to calm TypeScript down?

This works but feels clumsy, and misleading to the reader (because there is no reason to doubt the attribute will be present and an array).

```
const f = 'features' in e && Array.isArray(e.features) && thing.features[0];
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What library is it?

Comment: I don't think that matters for the purpose of the question does it? I'm not looking for a specific solution for only this one case.